# Haskell Typeclass for Tuples

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I was playing around with typeclasses and made this:

```
class Firstable f where
  fst :: f a -> a

class Secondable f where
  snd :: f a -> a
```

I then tried to add an implementation for `(,)` and realized that I could do:

```
instance Secondable ((,) a) where
  snd (x,y) = y
```

I'm pretty sure this works because `Secondable` should have kind `(* -> *)` where `((,) a)` has that type, however, I don't know how to implement `Firstable` for `((,) * a)` where `*` is the bound variable, In my interpretation I am trying to do the equivalent of:

```
instance Firstable (flip (,) a) where ...
```

Is there a way to do this in Haskell? Preferably without extensions?

Comment: AFAIK, no: you'd need `TypeSynonymInstances`, but type synonyms cannot be partially evaluated. But are you aware of the alternative with `MultiParamTypeClasses`? That's perhaps a bit ugly, but it works.

Comment: You might be interested in how the tuple package handles this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version with worse parametricity guarantees can be had with MPTCS and Fundeps or with TypeFamilies.

```
type family Fst p
type instance Fst (a,b) = a
type instance Fst (a,b,c) = a
```

...

```
class First p where
   fst :: p -> Fst p

instance Fst (a,b) where
   fst (a,_) = a

instance Fst (a,b,c) where
   fst (a,_,_) = a
```

...

but ultimately, you'll need to use some extensions.

Comment: Is `type instance Fst (a,b,c) = b` supposed to read `type instance Fst (a,b,c) = a` instead?

Answer (score 11):

You can use type families like so (A different take on what Edward wrote):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Firstable a where
  type First a :: *
  fst :: a -> First a

class Secondable a where
  type Second a :: *
  snd :: a -> Second a

instance Firstable (a,b) where
  type First (a, b) = a
  fst (x, _) = x

instance Secondable (a,b) where
  type Second (a, b) = b
  snd (_, y) = y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Firstable f where
    fst :: f a b -> a

class Secondable f where
    snd :: f a b -> b
```

Comment: This way only 2-tuples could be made an instance of that class, no? That would kind of defeat the purpose of having the type class to begin with.

Comment: @sepp2k First, he never specified the purpose and I interpreted it to mean he just wanted to generalize type constructors of (at least) two arguments.  Second, his two original classes have the exact same signature, implying he either got them wrong, or he should just use one class to describe both fields.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez yeah, I intended the tuples to be able to be implemented for (,),(,,)...

Comment: This approach will actually work if you're willing to accept counting from the right instead of from the left, but I don't think you're going to make it work the other way around.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, although in that case, you would want to do: `fst :: f a -> a`, `snd :: f b a -> b`, ...